# Preview PDF on android

Tags: android

I would like to preview a PDF document on android.

This is what I am using now.

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://ecare.stagnesloretolko.com/StudentImages/ReportCards/ANUSHREE_1521_2015-2016_TermII.pdf

I can not open pdf file they showing no preview available in mobile app.

Comment: What have you tried ? Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is broken.
Please look at below link http://ecare.stagnesloretolko.com/StudentImages/ReportCards/ANUSHREE_1521_2015-2016_TermII.pdf

Comment: https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://ecare.stagnesloretolko.com/StudentImages/ReportCards/ANUSHREE_1521_2015-2016_Term%20II.pdf        hello guyzz i really sorry for mistaken please look it now ???Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Hi @chandankumarchoudhary, can you try to rename file without space and try.

Comment: Hi @subrahmanyam boyapati, I am also try but they didnot work without space or with space

Comment: Hi @subrahmanyam boyapati sir, I am new android developer .So it's our kind requested to you that please tell me step by step procedure for this issue regarding solution.I am thankful to you.

Comment: have you tried without spaces in file name? I could able to see below link
https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true

Comment: Sir actually i have no idea about it please tell me intial step for remove space.....Thanks

Comment: where you hostel file go there and remove spaces and try to load that file in gview

Comment: hello sir please let me know that what is hostel file ? Actually i am new programmer and this is group type of project ,Please explain in simple ,

Comment: sorry its not hostel, hosted file.

Comment: it's ok sir but i have no idea where is hosted file .Please let me know where is hosted file in step by step .thanks in advance